# Is there a way to initialize a UserControl once all all properties have been passed into it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am currently creating a WPF application, and I've noticed something a little strange. Passing data into a UserControl via properties seems to happen with a delay.

```
    public partial class TestControl : UserControl
    {
        public string Subject { get; set; } = "Foo";

        public TestControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            Start();
        }

        public async Task Start()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Subject is: " + Subject);
            await Task.Delay(1);
            Debug.WriteLine("Subject is: " + Subject);
        }
    }
```

and in the Main window I set the Subject property of the UserControl:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApplication"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TestApplication.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <views:TestControl Subject="Bar"></views:TestControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the output I get the default value Foo printed out, and then 1 ms later I get Bar.

```
Subject is: Foo
Subject is: Bar
```

Is there a way to guarantee the initialization of the component with the passed-in value instead of the default value without artificially adding some delay for it to work?

Comment: You should probably read [Object Lifetime Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/object-lifetime-events?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). In your example, you could call your `Start` method in the initialized event, but you have to be careful using that event (see the link). The loaded event is much safer if you have complex initialization requirements.
Also, you should be getting a warning that says `Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed` because you are not awaiting your `Start` method.

Comment: Be aware that as soon as you want to bind a property of your control, e.g. like `Subject="{Binding SubjectInViewModel}"`, the property would have to be declared as [dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-properties-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0). In that case the timing would also be different, since Bindings are evaluated later. You would also have to take care not to explicitly set the control's DataContext, because that would break such Bindings. Besides that, use the `Loaded` event.

Answer (score 0):

There is no delay.

You are calling `Start` from the constructor of `TestControl` and since it is an `async Task` function it immediately returns from the method as soon as it hits the `await`.

Then, WPF can continue populating the control with its config data - thus setting `Subject` to `Bar`.

In the meanwhile the `await Task.Delay(1)` finishes and you now print the new value of `Bar`.

In effect, you're creating the perceived timing issue by calling a fire-and-forget method during object construction.

Comment: OK... So how do I have my `Start` method run only once `Subject` has been set to `Bar`?

Comment: @Alex - There will be an event raised by WPF after it has initialized the control. Put your code in there.